# iOS Is it possible to get information about current state of "Color Filter"?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to write an application where I need to know whether the device is in "grayscale" or normal mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it using `UIAccessibility.isGrayscaleEnabled` . Check the full documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility).